# Value error when no value error

Tags: python-2.7, undefined, defined

The following code triggers a value error:

```
from pygame import *
init()
from random import *
t = True
f = False
inventory = []
class block(object):
    def __init__(self,break_time,break_content,color):
        self.break_time = break_time
        self.break_content = break_content
        self.color = color
    def brek(self):
        inventory.append(self.break_content)
end = block(1-0,None,(0,0,0))
gem = block(10,"agem",(0,0,100))
stone = block(3,"cobble",(100,100,100))
iron = block(5,"iron_ore",(25,50,100))
dirt = block(2,"dirt",(139,69,19))
locations = [a for a in range (60)]
unervise = {}
def generate(x_axis):
    global unevise
    global locations
    for a in range(60):
        global unevise
        global locations
        if a == 0 or a == 1:
            unevise[(locations[a],x_axis)] = end
        if a in range(2,35):
            if a in range(2,10) and randint(1,10) == 1:
                unevise[(locations[a],x_axis)] = gem
            elif a in range(2,30) and randint(1,5) == 1:
                unevise[(locations[a],x_axis)] = iron
            else:
                unevise[(locations[a],x_axis)] = stone
        if a in range(35,40):
            unevise[(locations[a],x_axis)] = dirt
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ben/Documents/Python Files/My first comp openable.py", line 46, in <module>
    generate(a)
  File "C:/Users/Ben/Documents/Python Files/My first comp openable.py", line 28, in generate
    unevise[(locations[a],x_axis)] = end
NameError: global name 'unevise' is not defined
```

But the value is clearly defined, thrice in my program, twice globaling it inside the function.
I probably have overlooked some major key point- sorry.

Comment: You misspelled the name of the variable: it is called `unervise`, not `unevise`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `unervise`, not `unevise`:

```
unervise = {}
```

Also, there's no need for the multiple `global` declarations.

Comment: The reasons there are many is because it kept having errors- so I put more in.