# Tuple dictionary key not able to be retrieved

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples, pygame

One problem goes, another comes- I've got another(probably just as obvious) problem:

```
'tuple' object is not callable
```

from

```
for a in range(current_view_y,current_view_y+60):
    for b in range(current_view_x,current_view_x+80):
        if (b,a) in unervise:
            screen.blit(Surface(unervise[(b,a)].color()))
```

I don't think this is actually related to the pygame code, just the other bit ( so I THINK screen to surface is ignore-able.
(previous question with the dictionary generation code:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924723/value-error-when-no-value-error?noredirect=1#comment24432303_16924723)
Once again I apologize for how obvious this probably is- but I simply can't see it (and I can't post it on the previous question).
Most topics on this say a missing comma is to blame- but I only have one.

Comment: Please do include the full traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `.color` attribute of your `block` class as a method, but it is a tuple:

```
screen.blit(Surface(unervise[(b,a)].color()))
```

Remove the surplus `()`:

```
screen.blit(Surface(unervise[(b,a)].color))
```

Comment: I keep doing these things- problem is, anyone in my house knows no pygame so can't help me- thanks!

Comment: Never knew I could do that! Although (my fault of course) I have just managed to crash my computer by running my code- it even broke restarting. I am now really confused.

Comment: Whatever broke your computer has nothing to do with Python, I can tell you that much. :-)

Comment: Actually it did, I tried to both fill, blip and the previous code all on one line- and since fill changes the variable it is acting on, and does not actually return a value, it temporarily broke my computer.

Comment: It at most broke your code; I doubt that your computer boot procedure is dependent on Python code.  :-)

Comment: My computer is really messed up. I play with some of the advanced settings without knowing what im doing, and have installed loads of different programs which most I haven't uninstalled properly- anything may be linked!